# Is it possible to make the content of an email static using view_email_url in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I was wondering if there is a way to make the content of the email template using view_email_url static. Currently, I'm using a data extension in a journey that is constantly been updated, so when I send an email and the user clicks on the view_online_url the content is different than it was sent, I was thinking of using a "back up" data extension that stores only the data that was sent, but do not know if it's the right way because the email has 6 blocks and each block has 10 parameters. Any suggestions on how to approach this using view_email_url?